# Understanding mov in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, att

[address and data manipulation, click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK5ck.png)

```
mov $0x100, %eax
mov $0x105, (%eax)
```

In a 32bit little-endian architecture

Could someone explain me how these mov's are working?

I understand that the second mov is informing the processor to write on the memory address corresponding to the aex register the value 0x105, but I fail to understand why it is being written on the 0x100 address

Thanks for any help

Comment: please post code and specify the instruction set.

Comment: If both instructions are run in that order, the first instruction sets EAX to 0x100.  If those are taken as separate examples / questions, (where you don't know the starting value of EAX), you can't say anything about the store address for the `mov $0x105, (%eax)`

Comment: Perhaps we could do a better job of clearing up your misunderstanding if you explained what you think should be happening here - what address do you expect the value to be written to, if not 0x100?

Comment: That's the thing right, we don't have enough information to know the adress, right?
This question appeared in a test in my university and the solution they gave was that it was written on the address 0x100, 0x101, 0x102, 0x103
because it's a 4byte number

Comment: 0x100 is placed into _EAX_ and that is then used as the destination memory address in the second move `(%eax)`

Comment: Tehcnically speaking `mov $0x105, (%eax)` won't assemble given the assembler doesn't have enough information on what size of data the value 0x105 is. You'd usually resolve that by using movb, movw, movl etc.

Comment: Ohhh okay , I simply thought that the first mov was just placing the number 0x100 in eax register and that had nothing to do with the memory adress, but i think i get it now

Comment: @FredericoVicente the first move *does* place value 0x100 into `eax`, and has nothing to do with address - just like you wrote it. It's the second `mov`, which takes value in `eax` (being 0x100 after first `mov`) and uses it as memory address. The AT&T syntax of memory reference is: `displacement(base, index, scale)`, with `(%eax)` being shortcut to `+0(%eax,,)` or `+0(,%eax,1)`, whichever encoding the assembler will prefer (if the base can be empty, I'm actually not sure, as I don't bother with these subtleties, for me as programmer either of them will do the same job.

Comment: @PeterCordes EAX has been set to 0x100. Why we can't say anything about the store address for the `mov $0x105, (%eax)`? Doesn't it mean setting the value of memory address 0x100 to 0x105?

Comment: @starriet: I think you missed the part of my comment right before that where I said "*If those are taken as separate examples / questions*", rather than two instructions that run in sequence.  I think I was trying to come up with a plausible explanation for the answer to not be obvious, since the question already states they know that the 2nd `mov` is using EAX as the store address.  Or to point out that running them in sequence *does* mean that the effect of the first on EAX will influence the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
mov $0x100, %eax
```

it moves the immediate value `0x100` into the `eax` register

```
mov $0x105, (%eax)
```

it moves the immediate value `0x105` into the dereferenced address `0x100` from `eax` because you are using `(%eax)`. It has the value `0x100` you put in the previous step.

Think about the concept `pointer` in `C` which saves the address as its value - it uses `*ptr` to dereference the value while here it uses `(%register)`.

To help you get something into assembly, check out here: [CS107 Guide to x86-64](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs107/cs107.1222/guide/x86-64.html)

Comment: As noted in comments, `mov $0x105, (%eax)` won't assemble.  You need `movl $0x105, (%eax)` or `movw` to set an operand-size.  (Or `movb`, but this immediate won't fit in a byte.)